# Selenium IDE/Flow Control - gotoif condition

Tags: selenium-ide, flow-control

I'm new to gotoif condition in SeleniumIDE.
Trying to use it to test this scenario in the same test:

- If page displays "test" icon, then click Launch and skip next step.
- If page doesn't display "test" icon, then proceed to next step.

Answer (score 1):

If You allways have pictire (but diffrent) in this place, You can get Xpath and get scr atribue of this picture:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>//body/div/img@src</td>
    <td>urladress</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>'${urladress}'!= 'http://mypage.com/img/test.ico'</td>
    <td>marker1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Here commands for this picture</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>marker1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>'${urladress}'== 'http://mypage.com/img/test.ico'</td>
    <td>marker2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Here commands without this picture</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>marker2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

If it do not work you can use javascript function:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeBodyText</td>
    <td>body</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['body'].search('test.ico')}</td>
    <td>result</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${result}==-1</td>
    <td>marker1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Here commands for this picture</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>marker1</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${result}!=-1</td>
    <td>marker2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Here commands without this picture</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>marker2</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```